# Does the usage of String.Intern() have any meaning in this use case?

Tags: c#, string

In the app I'm developing I'm creating several objects that each have the following property:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the jumps text.
    /// </summary>
    public string JumpsText
    {
        get
        {
            return Jumps == -1 ? String.Empty : String.Format("{0} jump{1}", Jumps, Jumps != 1 ? "s" : String.Empty);
        }
    }
```

The objects are used to iterate a listview. Objects created can vary from 1 to up to 3000 which means that the string created from the above property can be the same for different objects.

My question is:

Would the use of String.Intern() like `String.Intern(String.Format("{0} jump{1}", Jumps, Jumps != 1 ? "s" : String.Empty))` be advised in this case. Will it have any impact on the memory used by the created strings?

Comment: How often is this called? How much variance do you have within `Jumps`?

Comment: It's called with each object. Jump value can be from -1 up to short.MaxValue().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a few thousand entries it does not matter at all. As a rule of the thumb as long as the Listview is not virtual due to performance and memory consumption reasons you do not need to worry about string interning.